# PHP regex title conversion / negative look ahead / toLowerCase

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, lowercase, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to convert some titles in my html pages to `<h2>`. The pattern is simple.

```
<?php
$test = "<p><strong>THIS IS A TEST</strong></p><div>And this is Random STUFF</div><p><strong>CP</strong></p>";
$pattern = "/<p><strong>([A-Z ]*?)<\/strong><\/p>/";
$replacement = "<h2>$1</h2>";
$test = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $test);
?>
```

Basically, grab anything that's between `<p><strong></strong></p>` that is capitalized. Easy enough, so here's the complicated bit.

Firstly, I need to make a single exception. `<p><strong>CP</strong></p>` must not be converted to `<h2>`. I tried adding `?!(CP)` right after the `<p><strong>` but it doesn't work.

Secondly, I need to be able to make the first letter capitalized. When I use "ucfirst" with "strtolower" on the preg_replace (ex:`ucfirst(strtolower(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $test)));`), it makes all the characters in the string to lowercase and ucfirst doesn't work as it's detecting "<" to be the first character.

Any hints or am I even going in the right direction?

---

EDIT

Thanks for the help, it was definitely better to use `preg_replace_callback`. I found that all my titles were more than 3 characters so I added the limiter. Also added special characters.
Here's my final code:

```
$pattern = "/<p><strong>([A-ZÀ-ÿ0-9 ']{3,}?)<\/strong><\/p>/";
$replacement = "<h2>$1</h2>";
$test[$i] = preg_replace_callback($pattern, create_function('$matches', 'return "<h2>".ucfirst(mb_strtolower($matches[1]))."</h2>";'), $test[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php .

You can create a custom function that is called on every match. In this function you can decide to a) not replace CP and b) to not put $1, but ucfirst.

Hope this helps & good luck.

Comment: Pattern for not replacing CP: `/<p><strong>((?!CP)[A-Z ]*?)<\/strong><\/p>/` and for data manipulation use `preg_replace_callback` as mentioned above.

Comment: or just check if `$match[1] == "CP"` and `return "<p><strong>CP</strong></p>"`